# xlsb PowerBI error External table is not in the expected format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

so I read that Excel binary format is faster and better, so I saved my table in this format. Unfortunately I found out that my other workbook which was importing one sheet from this now has problems and when I try to import that sheet again from this xlsb file it says DataFormat.Error: External table is not in the expected format
So is XLSB just unusable as data source for other workbooks?? Do I have to save it back as XLSX?

Comment: Take a look at [Importing xlsb into Power BI](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/importing-xlsb-into-power-bi/). I have also read something about it being possible if you only have one table per worksheet.  And that the connector is less efficient reading xlsb vs xlsx

Comment: And I have certainly been able to import xlsb into both Power Query in Excel, and also Power BI Desktop, although for the latter I had to install an old Access connector.  It is written, however, that the import process is more efficient using the more modern file types (xlsx/xlsm)

Answer (score 0):

OK so if nobody says otherwise I consider Excel binary format incompatible with PowerBI